# How to get string return from method?

Tags: ios, string, methods, random

Sorry for my stupid question.
How can i get string return from this following method?

```
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

-(NSString *) randomStringWithLength: (int) len {

    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: len];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
         [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
    }

    return randomString;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, this is what you need to call:

```
NSString *resultString = [self randomStringWithLength:10];
```

Note, that `[self randomStringWithLength:10]` is already a `NSString` object, so you can use it without declaring variable, e.g.:

```
NSLog(@"Result = %@;", [self randomStringWithLength:10]);
```